# can not login facebook when export apk eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I'm trying to use Facebook Android SDK to develop a  app with the Facebook Login. When I debug it run but when I export it to apk and run, it show notification invalid hash key...
When setting my app in [enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com)

I use two key for debug key and release key.I try log key hash in my app with method

```html
public static void showHashKey(Context context) {
            try {
                PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                        "com.example.tryitonjewelry", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES); //Your            package name here
                for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    Log.i("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                    }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            }
        }
```

And I see it like key debug so why the export of APK reappeared error. In error i see key invalid it not like either key I setting.

Comment: i think you are using debug hash key for signed apk also thats why you are getting that problem.Use Signed app hash key.

Comment: How I can use release key for export apk file?
I use keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Phohay\phohaycom.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64 to get key release and set it in facebook developer